# I use html2canvas to add a logo, heading, and table for downloading in PNG format

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to generate a single PNG image file containing a logo displayed on both the left and right sides of a header, along with a table. However, my current code displays these elements separately. I am seeking assistance in identifying my errors and integrating the components into a unified image file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        $('#export-btn').live('click', function() {
            var heading = "Amounts in PKR Mn; per share in PKR";

            var HTML_Width = $('.overview_table').width();
            var HTML_Height = $('.overview_table').height();

            var top_left_margin = 60;
            var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (60 * 2);
            var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1) + (60 * 2);

            var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;

            var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

            //var screenshot = document.getElementById('table-export');
            html2canvas($('.overview_table')[0]).then(function(canvas) {

                const fontHeight = 25;

                const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                canvas.width = canvas_image_width;
                canvas.height = canvas_image_height;

                ctx.font = fontHeight + "px Arial";
                ctx.textAlign = "left";
                ctx.fillStyle = "red"; // text color

                ctx.fillText(heading, 10, 25);

                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var logo = new Image();
                logo.src = "/sites/all/themes/images/logo.png";
                console.log(logo.src)
                canvas.width = canvas_image_width;
                canvas.height = canvas_image_height;

                ctx.drawImage(logo, 10, 10);

                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                var anchor = document.createElement('a');

                anchor.setAttribute("href", dataURL);

                anchor.setAttribute("download", "my-image.png");

                anchor.click();
                anchor.remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col2_1">
        <table class="overview_table " width="956" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width='270' class='hdcol aplcol'>2024</th>
                    <th class='hdcol aplcol'>2023 </th>
                    <th class='hdcol aplcol'>2022 </th>
                    <th class='hdcol aplcol'>2021 </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr class='table_row_white'>
                <td width='' class='txtright aplcol' style='text-align:left !important;'>25</td>
                <td width='' class='txtright'>40</td>
                <td width='' class='txtright'>50</td>
                <td width='' class='txtright'>60 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```